# How do I solve these arraylist questions?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to get the sum of the elements. How to achieve this?
not really homework, I jsut kind of missed the classes while I was ill and help

Below is my code :

```
    public class Main extends Actor
    {
       // method takes a list of Integer as a parameter and returns an int
        public int sum()
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            array.add(1);
            array.add(234);
            array.add(32);
            }
    }
```

Comment: You have a List of Integer.. How do you get the longest String?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "longest string"?

Comment: Sorry I added two questions together. they're separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the element of array and add them.

To find the sum:

```
 private int sum (List<Integer> array) {
      int sum =0;
      for(Integer i: array) {
         sum = sum + i;
      }
      return sum;
   }
```

I do not understand the second part of the question. When you say longest String. I think you mean largest number.

And if you mean largest number from the list you can use

```
Collections.max(array);
```

Comment: Now you're manually unboxing what would already be autounboxed.

Comment: thanks again. I have modified again.

Comment: Good. Sometimes we make easier things complicated.

Comment: I get grumpy when people upvote answers that are wrong.  Today they're downvoting answers that are correct.  I have given up understanding the users of this site.

Comment: I just wanted to help the person. I do not give much importance to number system.

Comment: All things considered, I couldn't remove the downvote until the post was edited (it was edited in the grace period but the downvote still stuck).